# Xubuntu 18.04 and DPI setting always resetting to 96 DPI

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, multiple-monitors, xfce, dpi

I have a problem that every time I lock screen and log back in in Xubuntu it changes DPI setting back to 96 as reported by `xdpyinfo | grep -B2 resolution`. I have two monitors set up as one screen. I have set up proper `DisplaySize` in `90-monitor.conf`

```
DisplaySize            527 296    # In millimeters
```

I have also set up `Xft.dpi` in `~/.Xresources`:

```
Xft.dpi:        124
```

On top of that, I have also set up the DPI in XFCE's control panel:

[image]

Does it maybe have something to do with the fact that every time I log in I get the display setup dialog?

[image]

Comment: It seems dpi setting can no longer be changed. I used the command *xrandr --dpi 166* under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but now it has no effect at all under Ubuntu 18.04. Probably all other options available to user like your XFCE control panel also use the same command. It could also be as a result of a command in *xrandr* :-(